# C - Copy contents of one char array to another using pointers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, char

I'm trying to write a simple C function to copy the contents of one char array to another using pointer arithmetic. I can't seem to get it working, can you tell me where I'm going wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void copystr(char *, const char *);

int main()
{

    char hello[6] = "hello";
    const char world[6] = "world";

    copystr(&hello, &world);

    return 0;
}

    void copystr(char *str1, const char *str2)
    {
        *str1 = *str2;                 //copy value of *str2 into *str1
        printf("%s %s", *str1, *str2); //print "world" twice
    }
```

Help appreciated, thanks.

EDIT:
Here is the working code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void copystr(char *, const char *);

int main()
{

    char hello[6] = "hello";
    const char world[6] = "world";

    copystr(hello, world);
    printf("%s %s", hello, world);

    return 0;
}

void copystr(char *str1, const char *str2)
{
    /*copy value of *str2 into *str1 character by character*/
    while(*str2)
    {
        *str1 = *str2;
        str1++;
        str2++;
    }
}
```

Comment: I get about 5 warnings about parameters not matching the functions called. What does *your* compiler tell you?

Comment: hmm, a technical note. If you are trying to change what your character array points to, you can't do that, but you can change the contents. You could declare it as a pointer to a string declared on the stack, and this would allow you to change the pointer, but changing the contents may (but may not) cause a segmentation fault.

Comment: You probably mean `copystr(hello, world)` (no &), and then the `copystr()` function only copies over a single character with `*str1 = *str2`, and finally, you want `printf("%s", str1)` (no *). Remember, C's `char` type is a single character. C has no "string" type.

Comment: @Bo Persson compiler says this:  
-------------- Build: Debug in ca04 (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

Target is up to date.
Nothing to be done (all items are up-to-date).


-------------- Run: Debug in ca04 (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

Checking for existence: C:\Users\user\Desktop\ca04\bin\Debug\ca04.exe
Executing: "C:\Users\user\Desktop\codeblocks-16.01mingw-nosetup/cb_console_runner.exe" "C:\Users\user\Desktop\ca04\bin\Debug\ca04.exe"  (in C:\Users\user\Desktop\ca04\.)
Process terminated with status -1073741510 (0 minute(s), 4 second(s))

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker Thank you very much for the advice, appreciate it.

Comment: @BurnsBA - I'm just trying to change the contents of the char hello array.

Comment: @somers then don't worry too much about my comment. But there are no strings in c, so you'll need something like negacao's answer which copies character by character.

Comment: @BurnsBA - Great, thanks so much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are only copying the first character of the string.

```
void copystring(char* str1, const char* str2)
{
    while(*str2)
    {
        *str1 = *str2;                 //copy value of *str2 into *str1
        str1++;
        str2++;
    }
}
```

and then in main, after calling copystring

```
    printf("%s %s", hello, world); //print "world" twice
```

But please don't do this! Use [strncpy](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strncpy/) in real life, if working with plain C strings.

Comment: last printf will print nothing because the pointer points to the last terminating character.

Comment: Doh! Thanks, @yakout.

Comment: Thank you very much negacao, really appreciate the help.  This is driving me insane! :)

Comment: Happy to help, @somers. :)

Comment: @negacao - If you have time could you explain the while loop to me a little more, I don't fully understand it. The condition part mostly.

Comment: [This page](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/string.h/strcpy#Usage_and_implementation) might be a good starting point. The code just loops through the second array one by one, copying each character to the first array.

Comment: @negacao - Thank you!